# date difference with linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

With this code:

```
 i.SpesaAlloggio = db.TDP_NotaSpeseSezB.Sum(p => p.Costo / (((DateTime)p.DayEnd)
                    .Subtract((DateTime)p.DayStart).Days + 1));
```

I receive this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be 
translated into a store expression.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try (it is not very efficient, but it will work):

```
i.SpesaAlloggio = db.TDP_NotaSpeseSezB.ToList()
             .Sum(p => p.Costo / (((DateTime)p.DayEnd)
             .Subtract((DateTime)p.DayStart).Days + 1));
```

**EDIT : This will be extremely slow for large tables, because it transfers whole table content form server**

Entity Framework tries to translate your expression to SQL, but it can't handle `((DateTime)p.DayEnd).Subtract((DateTime)p.DayStart)`. You have to make it simpler. `ToList()` gets all rows and then makes the calculation on application side, not in database.

With EF4, you could use [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_members%28VS.100%29.aspx) `DateDiff`

With EF1, you could create calculated field or view with this field and make calculation based on this field.

Comment: "it is not very efficient". It's not at all. How could you answer that?

Comment: @SandRock: It is horrible solution, but if table doesn't have many rows and code is executed rarely, this is acceptable. This solution is definitely not scalable, but works for small tables. I corrected my answer.

Comment: It is such a horrible solution that I would not even consider call it a solution, more like a problem maker than a solution.... Writing raw SQL would be a lot wiser than using this. (Yes, I saw the disclaimer, but yet...)

Answer (score 1):

Use a calculated DB field and map that. Or use `SqlFunctions` with EF 4 as LukLed suggested (+1).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for removing time:

```
public static DateTime RemoveHours(DateTime date)
{
    int year = date.Year;
    int month = date.Month;
    int day = date.Day;
    return new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```

and changed filtering condition:

```
var query =
   from trn in context.IdentityTransactions
   where trn.ClientUserId == userId && trn.DateDeleted == null
   orderby trn.DateTimeCreated
   select new
   {
       ClientServerTransactionID = trn.ClientServerTransactionID,
       DateTimeCreated = trn.DateTimeCreated,
       ServerTransDateTime = trn.ServerTransDateTime,
       Timestamp = trn.Timestamp,
       Remarc = trn.Remarc,
       ReservedSum = trn.ReservedSum,
   };


if (dateMin.HasValue && dateMin.Value > DateTime.MinValue)
{
    DateTime startDate = Converters.RemoveHours(dateMin.Value);
    query = from trn in query
                 where trn.DateTimeCreated >= startDate
                 select trn;
}
if (dateMax.HasValue && dateMax.Value > DateTime.MinValue)
{
    var endDate = Converters.RemoveHours(dateMax.Value.AddDays(1.0));
    query = from trn in query
                where trn.DateTimeCreated < endDate
                select trn;
}
```

dateMin and dateMax are nullable types and may be not set in my case.